# Issuse with session_start()

Tags: php

I am new with advance php. Please can you explain what this function does?

```
ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);
```

I have particular file named index.php in which if I start session I get following error on this function.

> Warning: ini_set() [function.ini-set]: A session is active. You cannot change the session module's ini settings at this time in [...]/main.inc.php on line 35

I have installed a module and that module is removing all main page sessions, which is why I put a condition on it - to check `session_start()` and that particular condition for session.

Answer (score 0):

`ini_set('session.use_trans_sid', 0);`
is to disable the transparent sid support, but this is default to be 0.

And you should put this before `session_start()`.

Comment: what is transparent sid support?.

Comment: PHP may automatically embed session IDs as part of URLs in a web page.
The automatic embedding is called "transparent SID support".

Answer (score 0):

isn't the error message self-explanatory?
you can't change session settings after it's already started. 
use this setting before calling session start, not after.

Comment: what is transparent sid support? As answered by one of replier.

Answer (score -1):

Always check wheter a session already exists before starting a new one, like so:

```
if(!session_id()) { session_start(); }
```

If no session_id is set, it will start a new session, otherwise it will do nothing.
As for use_trans_sid, xdazz pretty much covered that.